# c# restsharp System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#

I am new in C# and I'm getting an error **System.InvalidOperationException** with my code that calls API I created with PHP. My goal is to create a loading animation before the API is being loaded and hide it after.

```
loading.Visible = true;
login.Enabled = false;
var Client = new RestClient("http://localhost/online-lms/login.php");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
Client.ExecuteAsync<Form1>(request, (response) => {
    loading.Width = 200;
    login.Enabled = true;
    if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK) {
        JObject o = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
    }
});
```

Error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'loading' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.'

PS: I'm creating a Windows Form Application.

Any help with this?

Comment: Are you trying to create WPF application or windows forms application?

Comment: I am creating a Windows Form Application @ThiyaguRajendran

Comment: Its simple invoke your UIelement when you are trying to acces from different thread.. I will post an example now

Comment: You need to update UI using a delegate (callback)

Answer (score 1):

Invoke your UIelement to avoid cross thread **error.**

```
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {
            // run all your code here
        }));
        return;
```